# Selenium/JUnit - Tela de autenticação não é gravada/executada

Tags: eclipse, autenticação, junit, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo um POC para utilização do Selenium + JUnit 4 para testes funcionais de interface em uma ferramenta web. A ferramenta em questão exige autenticação ao ser aberta a URL, e o teste foi gravado no Selenium IDE/Firefox com todos os passos incluindo o preenchimento dessa autenticação.

Quando exportei o arquivo de testes para o java, ao executar o JUnit o Firefox é aberto, contudo o teste não sai da tela de login, e mesmo que eu grave esse caso no Selenium já partindo da "home" da ferramenta web, no teste executado no eclipse sempre será pedida a autenticação como se a página estivesse sendo aberta do zero.

Ao que pesquisei poderia ser usado WebElement com sendKeys, contudo não é possível abrir o console do Firefox nessa tela de autenticação para coletar a identificação dos elementos user/senha, que acredito ser Javascript.

Tela de autenticação é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei os seguintes conceitos como soluções, sem sucesso:

- [How to handle authentication popup with Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver)
- [Handling Browser Authentication using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395462/handling-browser-authentication-using-selenium)

Já modifiquei o método `setUp()` do *@Before* com todas as possibilidades que me vieram em mente mas o teste não desenvolve além dessa tela, mesmo se rodar ele direto no Selenium IDE/Firefox.

Any idea? =(

Update: Consegui fazer com que os dados de User e Senha sejam carregados automaticamente carregando um profile no código com esses dados já salvos, contudo não estava conseguindo fazer a ação de clicar no "OK", nem com robot, nem com "driver.get("http://user:pass@url");". 
Consegui realizar essa ação usando AutoIt pra gravar o movimento do mouse, e chamando o .exe depois no código, mas achei a solução meio estranha, há uma forma melhor de realizar essa ação de pressionar o "OK" sem o uso dessa tool?